# How to remove controller name in URL of codeigniter and need to add menu and submenu as URL name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to remove controller name from URL of codeigniter, for example:

```
www.example.com/controllername/functionname
www.example.com/welcome/aboutus
www.example.com/welcome/ourservices
```

I need URL as:

```
www.example.com/functionname
www.example.com/aboutus
www.example.com/ourservices
```

Then also i need to have sub menu for our services that URL should look like:

```
www.example.com/welcome/our services/service1
www.example.com/welcome/our services/service2
```

How to achieve this routing in codeigniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you ONLY want to remove 'welcome' from the URL,

you could do:

`$route['(:any)'] = "welcome/$1"`

Answer (score 0):

Go to `application/config/routes.php`

and add

```
$route['about-us'] = 'welcome/aboutus';
$route['our-services'] = 'welcome/ourservices';
```

---

Make sure your **function should not contain spaces**. it can be

1. aboutUs
2. about_us

   ```
   public function about_us()
   {
       # code...
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks if I am having more pages means how to add routes dynamically

Comment: For every page I need to add ... Is there any way to add dynamically for all pages say for example I am having 10-20 pages I should add 10-20 routes?...

Comment: @durai there is nothing easy unless u tried. Adding 20 page is big matter?? If you need to archice you hve to do it in any cost

Comment: It will work I am already using that .. I am looking for easier way like removing controller name welcome in one line code

Comment: **One line**. If you get anwer please post here. So i can learn tht too. Thnks

Comment: No there is no way like tht

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved By dynamic Routing. Open The file routes.php inside config folder and set the routes.
Example:

```
  $route['default_controller'] = 'Login';
  $route['404_override'] = '';
  $route['about-us']="Foldername(if-any)/ControllerName/FunctionName";
```

And to open about-us page u have to give path from controller like

```
      redirect(base_url('about-us'));
```